# How to make basic changes to ASP.Net Core with Docker Support?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've created my 'first' ASP.NET Core project with Docker support in VS2017.
I build and run and viola, it 'works'. A browser is launched, it loads http://localhost:32787/api/values and returns the expected "value1","value2" response... All is good.

So now I want to start working with this animal to make it do MY will.. get rid of the valuesController and create my own new testController. On run (select the 'docker' start command) it heads for api/values again...and again. (if I change values to test in the url it works as expected. But how do I get it to STOP going to api/values I cannot find any setting that will affect this change.

launchSettings.json is the 'intuitive' place to look. There I find a setting for launchUrl, which I change, first to just api/test (just as it was api/values OOTB) ... no joy, I go ahead and add the rest of the address 
so it reads: http://localhost:32787/api/value...

I do a search on the solution and in the file system and can find the word "Values" NOWHERE. 
I have found other articles that get into more advanced routes and adding them to the app.UseMvc() command in the Configuration (great, I'm sure I will need to use that soon) but something, somewhere is telling this project to go to http://localhost:32787/api/values and I want to know where that is and how to change it.

---

Pardon if this is a duplicate but I have tried any number of google searches for things like 'change default url in asp.net core with docker' and get polluted with irrelevant articles that show me many wonderful things that I don't need to know...YET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of VS, and you added *Docker* support either during, or after the solution was created, all you have to do is right-click on the project named *docker-compose*, choose Properties, and you can change the information there.

The default *Service URL* is what you need to focus on. The *Launch Browser* is set to Yes by default, which has little value in an API project after a short time. Change these to what you think you need. I set my *Launch Browser* to No, and in case I ever need it, set the *Service URL* to one that makes sense after doing some development.

I had a hard time finding these myself the first time I went digging.

Comment: you would think they would make something that fundamental easier to find...but...well Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

In case you try to browse with docker and it doesn't land on desired default route, then in your `launchSettings.json`, just add your desired prefix to `launchUrl` in the `Docker` node. For example to make `api` as your default route when running docker:

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/api"
}
```